# How to negatively match a specific value with RegEx

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to negatively match a specific value (let's say 42) using (JavaScript) RegEx.

I know how to positively match the value:

```
/^42$/.test(42); // true
/^42$/.test(43); // false
/^42$/.test(422); // false
```

I am looking for the inverse of this:

```
/somemagic/.test(42); // false
/somemagic/.test(43); // true
/somemagic/.test(422); // true
```

The solutions my Google-fu turned up didn't work for my use case because I care about matching the entire value being tested, not just a piece of it.

I have searched endlessly for this... any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an anchored negative lookahead:

```js
document.write(/^(?!42$)\d+$/.test(42) + "<br/>");
document.write(/^(?!42$)\d+$/.test(43) + "<br/>");
document.write(/^(?!42$)\d+$/.test(422));
```

The `(?!42$)` lookahead checks at the very beginning of the string if the string is `42` (since `$` asserts the end of the string). Thus, `42` does not match `\d+` pattern.

This is a good technique to add exceptions to more generic patterns, like shorthand or character classes, and even patterns with optional groups.